# How can we change the ROOT context of PUblisher in APi manager

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I am uisng wso2 api manager 1.8 i change the webroot context in carbon.xml
from  / to  /test

I am able to access the Carbon with the url XXX:9443/test/carbon
but when i tried to access XXX:9443/store or xxx:9443/publisher it is rediredting to carbon url. can any one please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

You need to change context in the  the site.json of store and publisher also.

In API store edit wso2am-1.8.0/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/store/site/conf/site.json  file

"context" :"with you context"

In API publisher edit wso2am-1.8.0/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/publisher/site/conf/site.json  file

"context" :"with you context"